# Changing tag width in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

Hi currently all my tags are of a same width. how do I set each individual tag with different width. For example, total is 100% I have 6 tags. I want the width to be different base on total value I put. like my last tagname is H+60 which is equal to 100%. my first tag will be H+15, which is 25% and so on.

currently this is what i tried.

```
var n = $(".nav li").length;
var w = (100/n);
$(".nav li").width(w+'%');
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show here.?

Comment: Java != JavaScript also, your question is unclear

Comment: Your question should be tagged javascript (and I suspect you use jQuery too?). Also, the java tag should be removed.

Comment: @Magnilex am not able to edit as suggested edit is pending

Comment: Sorry guys just started on html using javascript. currently I'm stuck. This is what I tried so far. http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/77/ . so sorry if my question is unclear.

Comment: What you show as what you tried is code that makes the `li` elements the same width. What did you try to achieve what you described as the goal? I cannot understand what the mystic H is in the description and what would be left to other elements if the first one occupies 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set width for each li you must write the width assign code inside each:

```
  var n = $('#nav li').length; //count length outside each
  $('#nav li').each(function()
  {
     var textInside = $(this).find("a").text(); //get number from text
     var w = //count width
     $(this).width(w+'%');  // assign width
   });
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure what you mean by get number from text. Do you mean like find("li") with text("5")???

Comment: I mean get the text inside li. for example:0, 5,10,15 ...60